# spring cloud stream consumer exchange connection retry

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-webflux, spring-cloud-stream, spring-rabbit

I have rabbitmq consumer with reactive spring cloud stream

```
@Bean
public <T> Consumer<Flux<Message<Subscription>>> exportConsumer() {
    return new ExportSubscriptionConsumer<>();
}
```

and below are the configurations

```
spring:
cloud:
    function:
        definition: exportConsumer
    stream:
        rabbit:
            bindings:
                exportConsumer-in-0:
                    consumer:
                        bindQueue: true
                        queueNameGroupOnly: true
                        declareExchange: false
                        bindingRoutingKey: smfexportconsumer
        function:
            bindings:
                exportConsumer-in-0:
                    destination: jms.durable.queues
        bindings:
            exportConsumer-in-0:
                group: smfexportconsumer
```

Issue i have is it, after application consuming the few messages suddenly it throws me a error.

```
Shutdown Signal: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=404, reply-text=NOT_FOUND - no exchange 'exportConsumer-in-0' in vhost '9509bf37-8afc-486e-ac98-61034066671d', class-id=50, method-id=20)
```

If i restart the application it works for a while but again same issue!
Do i have option to configure retry here, couldn't found any such configurations [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit.html#_reference_guide)
or
Do i have option to configure my custom retry logic.
Kindly help.

[EDIT]

```
messageFlux
            .doOnNext(s -> logger.info("Got message: {}", s))
            .map(Message::getPayload)
            .flatMap(this::converToCharacters)
            .map(User::getId)
            .flatMap(this::getUser)
           .onErrorContinue((throwable, o) -> logger.error(throwable.getMessage()))
```

Inside the convert method, I have an API call.

```
return webClient.get()
            .uri(uriBuilderFactory.builder().path("/authorize").build())
            .retrieve().bodyToMono(String.class)
            .publishOn(Schedulers.immediate())
            .timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(10))
            .map(s1 -> new User(s, s1));
```

Now the question I have is if I get a time out with the above endpoint, how do I handle it? is it using

```
onErrorContinue
```

or do I have the option of global error handling?

[EDIT-2]
Sample code [here](https://github.com/snofty/learning-spring-cloud-stream)

Comment: We need to look at your consumer, hard to say

Comment: ` .onErrorContinue(ExportDeliveryException.class, (throwable, o) -> getaContinue(throwable))` I was have custom exception handling. It was getting throwing error out.

Comment: I may need to continue my remaining process only if a specific error I got and for other use cases I may need to skip the message, consume a new message is it possible?

Comment: Everything is possible, but as I mentioned before, until we look at your consumer there is nothing more to add

Comment: @OlegZhurakousky Updated, please have a look. hope I'm able to showcase my problem.

Comment: I can't look at code snippets as they do not communicate full context. Please create a small app that reproduces the issue and push it to github somewhere so we can take a look

Comment: @OlegZhurakousky added the repo link, please have a look.

Comment: I asked for a bare minimum project that only shows how to reproduce the issue (relevant to s-c-stream), but you have given me project that uses open telemetry, mongo db etc. . . Please understand this is open source (not a support channel), we have very limited time and if you want help you need to help us as well.